# Kafka Connect: Error detection when worker fails

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'am submitting a connector to kafka. The connector created is sftp connector. Now when the password is wrong the connector sends back success response when the connector fails. The password is wrong response is not given at that time. This is a single scenario there could be mutliple scenarios like this. Now when I use the `<host>/connectors/<connector-name>/status`, I get the error saying failed to establish connection. But this endpoint has a little delay. If I'am immediately trying after creating the connector, I may not get any response(404).

What is the proper way of handling this using the status api call.Is there any delay that needs to be used before firing this API. Or can it be handled while submitting the connector to API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the connector, it naturally needs to load the JAR(s) responsible for the tasks, then distribute the tasks to actually start the connector code (which is responsible for connecting to the SFTP server with the connection details).

Therefore, the delay is natural, and there's no way to know your connection details are incorrect unless you try to use them before launching the connector.

Comment: How can I try to use it if Iam not creating the connector? I didnt quite get it.

Comment: The situation could be when a client is actually submitting the connector configuration. What could be the best possible way to handle in such scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The only way to detect a connection errors would be to establish the same connection that the connector would run prior to submitting the config, outside of Connect framework. This problem isn't unique to the stfp connector; jdbc or S3 connectors would have the same issue if invalid/missing credentials were given

Comment: I understood this problem isn't unique to sftp connector, I was wondering if there would be  a way to authencticate all the credentials or configs passed and getting to know it. The status API would get the information whether the connector has failed or not, but there is a delay and is not predictable delay. After deploying the connector I was trying to see if it worked well, but the unpredicatble delay is causing the probelm. Is there anyway to deal with the delay like polling for a few times or polling after a few seconds(just made up ways), I was wondering what could be standard way.

Comment: Polling is the only way I know of, but like you said, it's not predictable. Personally, we scan the statuses every 5 minutes or so using a Python script, then send alerts to a Slack channel